# Solucionar el error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: array

tengo un problema con mi código el cual no he podido resolver. A la hora de compilar mi código no me marca error, pero cuando corro mi clase Aplica me marca error en el método "calcuar"

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load
> from int array because "this.Pago" is null    at
> Estudiantes.mostrar(Estudiantes.java:36)  at
> AplicaEstudiantes.main(AplicaEstudiantes.java:7)

**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Estudiantes{
   private int K[];
   private int VC[];
   private int NC[];
   private int Pago[];
   private int total=0;
   public void k(){
      int total;
      K = new int [5];
      for (int i=0; i<K.length; i++){
         K[i]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar código del est udiante"+i+": "));
      }
   }
   public void vc(){
      VC = new int [5];
      for (int i=0; i<VC.length; i++){
         VC[i]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar valor de crdito del estudiante"+i+": "));
      }
   }
   public void nc(){
      NC =new int [5];
      for (int i=0; i<NC.length;i++){
         NC[i]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar # de creditos tomados por el estudiantes"+i+": "));
      }
   }
   public void calcular(){
      Pago = new int [5];
      for(int i=0;i<Pago.length;i++){
         Pago[i]= (VC[i]*NC[i])+210;
         total=total+Pago[i];
      }
   }
   public void mostrar(){
      for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Codigo alumno "+K[i]+" Total a pagar: "+Pago[i]);
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total de pago de los alumnos: "+total);
   }
}**
```

**

```
public class AplicaEstudiantes{
   public static void main (String[]args){
      Estudiantes mi = new Estudiantes();
      mi.k();
      mi.vc();
      mi.nc();
      mi.mostrar();
   }
}
```

No se si puedan ayudarme, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Hola Vane. Lo que ocurre es que dentro del método mostrar() el arreglo Pago[] no está definido. No sé lo que deseas hacer, pero ten en cuenta que en for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Codigo alumno "+K[i]+" Total a pagar: "+Pago[i]);
      } Pago[] no está definido Deberías hacer, por ejemplo, Pago[] = new int[5], y asignar valores a cada posición. Saludos y gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)